# Java swing file chooser date filter or file dialog date filter

Tags: java, swing, filedialog, filechooser

give sample code for getting files of current date or req date in file chooser or file dialog?
i need to filter files with date in file dialog?

Comment: Try out something yourself please. A hint - check if you can use file filter.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: ya.. but i cant filter with date in file dialog

Comment: Why not? The File class has a lastModified() method you can use in your FileFilter.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'm not sure if there is an existing File Filter using dates, so the best and quick solution for me was to implement my own Filter:

```
public class DateFileFilter extends FileFilter  
{    
     public boolean accept(File file)  
     {   
          GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar();//I get the today value  

          GregorianCalendar fileDate = new GregorianCalendar();  
          fileDate.setTimeInMillis(file.lastModified());//Here I get date info of the file 

          //Compare the current month and year  
          //with the month and yearthe file was  
          //last modified  
          return (((date.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) ==  
                fileDate.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH)) &&  
               (date.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR)  ==  
                fileDate.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR))) ||  
               file.isDirectory());  
    }   

    public String getDescription()  
    {  
        return "This is my filter for dates (:";  
    }  
}
```

Then you can add your filter to the JFileChooser:

```
JFileChooser jf = new JFileChooser();
jf.setFileFilter(/*HERE MY DATE FILTER*/);
```

For File Dialog, the process should be similar:

```
DateFileFilter filter = new DateFileFilter();
FileDialog dialog = new FileDialog(parent, "Choose File");   

        dialog.setFilenameFilter(filter);  

        dialog.show();  

        String selectedFile = dialog.getFile();
```

But I think that you can also implement the "Filter" interface instead of make an "extends".

Hope it helps, best regards (:

Comment: Why the use of `GregorianCalendar`?  You should be using `Calendar.getInstance()`, better yet, simply use `new Date()`.  `Date` (and `Calendar`) have `before`, `after` and `compareTo` methods for comparing `Date` objects. It seems like a lot of extra work for little gain - IMHO

Comment: can you do the same for file dialog??

Comment: I made an edit, hope it helps you. @MadProgrammer, thanks for your observation, I will consider it for refactoring my code.

Comment: its not filtering even when i mentioned as false in accept function in filtering